# Direct Line API - Bot Framework / Hero Cards and Attachments

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, botconnector, direct-line-botframework

I just started using the Direct Line API (1.1) and I saw that it doesn't let you know if a conversation was showed inside a Hero Card or a Button for example.

```
 {
      "id": "fBPDq9JSeL|000000000000000004",
      "conversationId": "fBPDq9JSeL",
      "created": "2016-11-28T20:22:20.6035604Z",
      "from": "portosegurobot",
      "text": "Health For Pets\n\nNossa missão é proporcionar a cães e gatos uma vida mais saudável e feliz.\n\nAcesse e saiba mais\n\n(Acesse) https://health4pet.com.br/",
      "images": [],
      "attachments": [],
      "eTag": "W/\"datetime'2016-11-28T20%3A22%3A21.3990939Z'\""
    }
```

The code above was showed (in the emulator) in a hero Card with a Button (card action). The Direct Line API doens't flag that? Is there a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hero cards / attachments are not supported in DirectLine v1.1; you won't receive anything in the attachments collection.

If you want to support Cards, you might have to do something custom as shown in the [DirectLine](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine) sample. There, the bot is [sending the hero card](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine/DirectLineBot/DirectLineBotDialog.cs#L33) through the ChannelData field and the client is [parsing that](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine/DirectLineClient/Program.cs#L77) accordingly.

I haven't used DirectLine v3.0, but based on the [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/) it seems that now attachments might be supported so you might want to take a look to that.

Comment: I tested the 3.0 and it's working fine, I just hope it's stable. Thank you!!